# Splitting strings unhashable type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have never split strings in Python before so I am not too sure what is going wrong here.

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('####################')

location = owm.weather_at_place('Leicester, uk')
weather = location.get_weather()
weather.get_temperature('celsius')
temperature = weather.get_temperature('celsius')

print(temperature[5:10])
```

Error received

```
sudo python weather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weather.py", line 10, in <module>
print(temperature[5:10])
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: Are you under the impression that `temperature` is a string? It's not a string. It looks like a dict to me.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm starting in the dark with Python here, Thank you I will try and figure it out from here and let you know I get on ;)

Comment: Don't convert the dictionary to a string and then slice it, dictionaries' order is not guaranteed and you'll most likely will get garbage out of it.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen huh? Strings, ints, and floats **are hashable**, lists **are not**.

Comment: @NathanK Any reason you were assuming `get_temperature` would return a string? Why not a `float` or `int`?

Comment: Print is your friend. When in doubt about a variable, `print(type(temperature), repr(temperature))` can give very useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_temperature` returns a dictionary, which you're then trying to index with a `slice` object, which is not hashable. e.g.

```
>>> hash(slice(5, 10))                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                             
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                          
TypeError: unhashable type
```

To get the temperature, you need to get it from the dictionary like this:

```
temperature['temp']
```

Comment: Thank you, That makes sense now. I was unaware of the dictionary type, I think its time to get my Python book out the cupboard :D